# what does "derivative" means in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

In image processing and especially edge detection, when we apply sobel convolution matrix to a given image, we say that we got the **first derivative** of the input image, and when applying the laplacian matrix to the initial image we say that we got the **second derivative**.

Taking into consideration that in both cases we applied the same operation (img * matrix), then why the first operation gave us the **first** derivative, and the second one gave us the **second** derivative and not the fifth ? is the values of the mask (convolution matrix) which decide which derivative we got ? or I'm already mistaken in my description ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: I'm null in mathematics, if you have a logical response away from maths please post it and I'll mark it as the _best answer_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the numbers in the filter kernel in just 1 dimension for simplicity. For a Sobel and  Prewitt matrix you have something that roughly looks like this

`[-1,0,1]`.

Convolving this with your image basically computes the difference between the pixel values of the neighboring pixels. You apply `0` to the current pixel, `1` to the pixel on the right and `-1` to the pixel on the left. This gives a first order difference:

`next pixel - previous pixel`,

i.e. first derivative.

But now look at a Laplacian operator. It looks something like `[1, -2, 1]`. This computes the difference of differences. To see how, note that

`[1,-2,1]` corresponds to

`next - 2 x current + previous`

i.e.

`next - current - current + previous`

i.e.

`(next-current) - (current-previous)`

Now notice how this is a diference of differences. `(next - current)` is like a 1st derivative. `(current - previous)` is like 1st derivative. Their difference is like a 2nd derivative.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank's @Atul

Comment: What would be a 3rd image derivative?

Comment: @mpnm You can apply the "next pixel minus previous pixel" operation to the Laplacian of the image. That should give you the third derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Operations like `img`$*$`matrix` are, in a generic, all convolutions. And derivatives are instance of convolutions. But convolutions are much more generic. When looking at edges, one can use derivatives at different orders. So you can have different such matrices representing different derivatives. If you convolve two such  matrices representing a first derivative, you can get `matrix`$*$`matrix`, which is just another kind of (convolution) `matrix`, but now representing a second derivative (under some conditions I won't detail now).

[EDIT after  [Atul Ingle]](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/1825/atul-ingle) The choice of the coefficients in `img` drives its behavior. On a discrete image, `img` can **emulate**  different discretized derivative behaviors, potentially in different directions. Discretizing oriented operators is a complex operations. For instance, you can find [here](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6931127/) at least three different $3\times 3$ versions for the discrete Laplacian:

[image: discrete Laplacian]

Here, are two recent references if you want to dig deeper:

- [Corner Detection and Classification Using Anisotropic Directional Derivative Representations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2013.2259834), Peng-Lang Shui and Wei-Chuan Zhang, 2013

> This paper proposes a corner detector and classifier using anisotropic
>   directional derivative (ANDD) representations. The ANDD representation
>   at a pixel is a function of the oriented angle and characterizes the
>   local directional grayscale variation around the pixel. The proposed
>   corner detector fuses the ideas of the contour- and intensity-based
>   detection. It consists of three cascaded blocks. First, the edge map
>   of an image is obtained by the Canny detector and from which contours
>   are extracted and patched. Next, the ANDD representation at each pixel
>   on contours is calculated and normalized by its maximal magnitude. The
>   area surrounded by the normalized ANDD representation forms a new
>   corner measure. Finally, the nonmaximum suppression and thresholding
>   are operated on each contour to find corners in terms of the corner
>   measure. Moreover, a corner classifier based on the peak number of the
>   ANDD representation is given. Experiments are made to evaluate the
>   proposed detector and classifier. The proposed detector is competitive
>   with the two recent state-of-the-art corner detectors, the He & Yung
>   detector and CPDA detector, in detection capability and attains higher
>   repeatability under affine transforms. The proposed classifier can
>   discriminate effectively simple corners, Y-type corners, and higher
>   order corners.

- [Differentiation of discrete multidimensional signals](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2004.823819), Farid, H. and Simoncelli, E. P., 2004

> We describe the design of finite-size linear-phase separable kernels
>   for differentiation of discrete multidimensional signals. The problem
>   is formulated as an optimization of the rotation-invariance of the
>   gradient operator, which results in a simultaneous constraint on a set
>   of one-dimensional low-pass prefilter and differentiator filters up to
>   the desired order. We also develop extensions of this formulation to
>   both higher dimensions and higher order directional derivatives. We
>   develop a numerical procedure for optimizing the constraint, and
>   demonstrate its use in constructing a set of example filters. The
>   resulting filters are significantly more accurate than those commonly
>   used in the image and multidimensional signal processing literature.

Comment: Thank's for your answer @Laurent , but I'm afraid that this don't answer my question yet, I just want to understand why sometimes `img`*`matrix` give us the **first** derivative (sobel, prewitt..), and at other times it give us the **second** derivative (laplacian...).

Comment: @RedaLM That's due to the numbers in the filter matrix. If you have something like `[-1,0,1]` it is taking the difference between neighboring pixel values i.e. 1st derivative. But if you have something like `[1,-2,1]` it's taking the difference of the difference i.e. 2nd derivative.